# Can never log back in after my laptop suspends

Tags: login, suspend

i bought a laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 5 Flex) two days ago and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, after configuring everything i needed i noticed now that when my laptop suspends i can never log back in, the 'user icon' and 'show password icon' are bugged and there's a message at the bottom saying Snapd User Session Agent, i will be leaving a screenshot aswell

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well i tried to submit the photo but i'm new here and couldn't

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot to imgur and post the link here?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6CishF7 here it is

Comment: Should also mention, i can't write my password nothing works at all but not like it freezes because i can still move my mouse around and click stuff, it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Press `ctrl + alt + f4`. It will open a virtual terminal. Can you login with your username and password (when you write your password in the terminal, no character will be shown in the screen)? If you can login, enter the command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^`